# How to make a equation hold true with 1000 numbers and 3 types of operators

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, logic

I have 1000 numbers and a target that's 37. I need to add plus, minus or times between all my numbers to make the equation hold truth. I have to use all numbers. The min value of my numbers is 0 and the max is 9. The instructions doesn't say anything about the usage of parentheses.
Ex: [2,3,4,6,5,1,0,7,9,8...etc is randomly repeated until the list reaches 1000 numbers] = 37

Is there any obvious ways of tackling this with an algorithm? I don't need actual code, rather examples on ways of thinking in words, and then the names or links to code that are "thinking" in the suggested way.

My first thought was to start from the right and try to get to 37 with the numbers that appears before the first 0 appears, and then multiply the first 0 with the digit to the left of it:

```
1. My list with numbers: 
[...lots of numbers, 0,3,1,9,5,5] = 37

2. Split the list to:
[...lots of numbers,0]
and 
[3,1,9,5,5]

3.
- Multiply the last zero with the left number of the first list above to eliminate all those numbers and make it easier to calculate. 

- Try different operators in different combinations between the numbers in the second list: [3,6,5,5] until I get 37
Ex: 
5*5 = 25 (remember 25 if not same as the target, don't use combo again)
25+9 = 34 (remember 34 if not same as the target, don't use combo again)
34-1 = 33 (remember 34 if not same the target, don't use combo again)
34+3 = 37
```

I suppose I might need to use a recursive function for it to remember how near you've come the target for every calculation but not sure if above even is an established strategy.

Answer (score 0):

1 - This might not be possible - if you have only one kind of non null number and/or 0s there is no way you can reach 37 - it is a prime number.
2 - More generally if the gcd of your non null numbers is greater than 1 (ex : 2,4 and 6 which gcd is 2) you can't solve you problem
3 - To the contrary if the gcd is 1, then you can find linear comnbinations of these numbers  so that X1.a1+X2.a2++++Xn.an=1 . If you have "enough" such numbers multply everything by 37 and you can find your target.